# how can i fix the problem with format on save in vs code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, autoformatting

Well "format on save" (in Vs Code) doesn't work, also tried Prettier but it doesn't work for React to.
Someone help!

format on save and Prettier in Vs code dont work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Default Formatter option set to Preitter?
File > Preferences > Settings and then search for the Default Formatter option and select Prettier from the dropdown menu.

If this doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall the Prettier extension.

last, of all is enable format on save enabled?